# Why C# doesn't have Decimal(x,y)?

Tags: c#, floating-point

Why I can't declare my variable as :

```
public decimal(1,1) Foo {get; set;}
```

In Sql (example in Microsoft Sql) I can write:

```
DECLARE @foo DECIMAL(1,1)
SET @foo = 1.0 / 3
SELECT @foo
```

and have nice `0.3` without bothering about [binary floating point](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) problems when comparing with other floating values. Instead I must write getters an setters:

```
public double Foo
{
    get { return Math.Round(_foo, 4); }
    set { _foo = Math.Round(value, 4); }
}
```

I need precision like 0.xxxx.

### Update:

Simple example:

JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader(reader) gives me value 14.16904729, and data from other source is 14.1690472890166. This is data set for unit testing and I can't just:

```
result.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

because of floating point representation. Now I must exclude some fields, write setters, getters.

Comment: or, you know, use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) rather than `double`...

Comment: Because C# is not SQL.

Comment: In addition, C# also doesn't support Stored Procedures and Views, BTW.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was asking about `decimal(x,y)` not `decimal`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Example with SQL is for illustrating the problem...

Answer (score 4):

Because you can not? I mean, come on - there is a defined decimal data type in .NET and it does not have the functionality because it was not deemed important. Want to argue what opinion the .NET langauge dev had for that? This is off topic.

I personally find the decimal situation in .NET very disappointing and would love Decimal32, Decimal64 and Decimal128 according to IEE754 standard - and the same in SQL Server.

But then, what I would like and what it there are two things and I am not in charge of those parts and can not make those changes. A more unified and more flexible system - according to IEE standards, on top, would be great, though.

Comment: My complaint with `Decimal` isn't that it's too big, but rather it's a floating-point type.  Sixteen bytes would be enough to accommodate a 20.16 fixed-point format, which should be adequate for all the purposes that Decimal can fulfill; using fixed-point math would be faster than decimal floating-point and would avoid much of the quirkiness associated with the latter.

Comment: Actually my complain is that decimal is not a standard decimal as per IEEE754 decimal definition (which, granted, was done later) so it wastes space and will never be hardware accelerated (which the IEEE ones likely will be soon). And there is still no standardized storage system between sql server and .net ;(

Comment: The time for floating-point decimal math has come and gone (it was pretty well obsolete by 1990).  The only decimal value type I see as making any sense on today's computing hardware would either be form of long integer type divided by a some fixed scaling factor, or possibly a pair of numbers whose scale differs by a power of five [e.g. for a 128-bit type with 64-bit halves H and L, the value would be H*16777216+L/1000000000000; the whole number portion of L can be produced by right-shifting by 12 and dividing by 32-bit value 244140625.]

Comment: If you want to use an IEEE type for decimal-ish things, I'd suggest using an 80-bit floating-point value, scaled up by a factor of 15,625.  That could accurately store the product of any multiple of 0.000001 times any representable `double`.  If Microsoft weren't so opposed to the 80-bit types that were supported by even early-1980's PCs, calculations with those would be many orders of magnitude faster than `Decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Or may be you can use

```
decimal _Foo;

public decimal Foo{
get{
    return Foo;
}
set {
    _Foo =new decimal(X,X,X,X,X); // you can use here your scale or precision
}
}
```

Comment: As I know decimal(1,1) is sql : first means the length of your number, the second the fixed decimal size, I don't judge poeple or try to be a smart AXX ! @TomTom